# SQL Alchemy: Loading Models and testing relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I can't find concrete examples to test relationships.

I have 2 models (Imagine Twitter, users can follow each other):

```
class User(Base):
    """Table schema containing profiles."""

    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True)

    following = relationship('User',
        secondary='followers',
        primaryjoin='User.id==Follower.user_id',
        secondaryjoin='Follower.user_id==User.id'
    )   


class Follower(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'followers'

    user_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    follows_user_id = Column(UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
```

To test it, I create a user and some relationships. I would like to find the following relations:
1. Given a user, find all of his followers.
2. Given a user, find all of the users he follows.

Hence, I tried:

```
u1 = User(id=uuid4())
u2 = User(id=uuid4())

f1 = Follower(user_id=u1, follows_user_id=u2)
f2 = Follower(user_id=u1, follows_user_id=u1)

print(u1.following)
>>> []
```

However this is an empty list. Why? I expected to see `[u1, u2]`.

I additionally tried:

```
u1 = User(id=uuid4())
u2 = User(id=uuid4())

f1 = Follower()
f1.user_id = u1
f1.follows_user_id = u2 

session.add(u1)
session.add(u2)
session.add(f1)
session.commit()
session.query(u1.following)
```

Comment: Why would you expect this to work without a session?

Comment: @roganjosh because I initiated the classes. I assumed the relationship would work, and I'd be able to see related objects.

Comment: By default relationships are lazy loaded, which means a SQL call is made. Therefore you need to persist those objects somehow before being able to access them. [More on this here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html#lazy-loading)

Comment: @mathiascg thanks, I had a read. Could you point me in the right direction as I think my relatioinships are incorrect? `can't adapt type 'User'`

Comment: I'm a little confused by the semantics but I think either the primary or secondary join should reference ```Follower.follows_user_id```. The way it's written a User will always only follow itself. Could you provide some more context about the error?

Comment: I guess my problem is understanding the primary/secondary joins on a self referencing table. How to structure them, do I add relationships in the association table? Because then, I have 2 relationships to the same User table with different backrefs